# WCF service call returns '407 Proxy Authentication Required'

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, proxy

I am hosting a WCF webservice (on Azure) and have shipped a WPF desktop application to a client who (obviously) tries accessing the service through a proxy.

The service calls fails, returning

> The remote server returned an unexpected response: 407 Proxy
>   Authentication Required

The `ServiceModel` section of the client app.config file looks like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ILicensing"  closeTimeout="00:00:15" openTimeout="00:00:15"
                 receiveTimeout="00:00:15" sendTimeout="00:00:15" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="xxxxxxx"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ILicensing"
                contract="Cloud.ILicensing" name="BasicHttpBinding_ILicensing" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

That's basically all I know.

I would know like to fix this behavior by modifying the app.config file and/or the web.config file of the service (which shouldn't matter, as the service is not reached anyways).

As far as I have understood, there is the attribute `useDefaultWebProxy` of the binding node, which asks to look up the system proxy configuration and use this for connecting to the service. However, as the default value is `true`, I would expect that setting it to `true` explicitly doesn't change anything (that's basically the definition of a default, I guess).

1. What can be reasons for the failing proxy authentication, considering `useDefaultWebProxy` is not set and therefor should be `true` due to it's default value?
2. How can the app.config be modified in order to fix the issue considering the limitied information? Basically: What do I need to know/ask my client (i.e. proxy server address) and where do I need to insert the information in my client config file?
3. How can I set up a test environment on my local machine which mimics the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For **1** and **2**, you need to configure `System.Net` to provide default credentials for the default proxy - it doesn't do this by default (because hidden callback code in apps with automatic access to the internet would be bad).

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
</system.net>
```

For **3**, I'm not entirely sure how you would be able to test this locally as you need a machine to act as the proxy and these are typically domain controller type machines. You could simulate with 2 VMs but I hope you have a powerful machine in order to do so plus it seems like a lot of effort to test this.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is the kind of answer I hoped for, as it's simple to fix and a clear explanation to what is wrong! I will try and definitely let you know if it worked. For 3, thank you very much, too, although I hope I don't need this then.

Comment: Hi toadflakz. The customer replaced the config with the fix you suggested and it simply works. Great job, thank you so much, this really helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from code

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```